# Change color for keywords within a custom command

Tags: color, code

**Problem:**

I am using a custom command to color keywords within the custom command `\code`. However, this will color everything blue as illustrated in MWE. I would like everything between `<` and `>` to be coloured in pink. The solution should only target the command `\code`.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Colors
% --------------------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{editorBlue}{cmyk}{1, 0.35, 0, 0}
\definecolor{editorPink}{cmyk}{0, 1, 0, 0}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Command for inline code
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\code}[1]{
  {\color{editorBlue}\texttt{#1}}
}

\begin{document}

\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut pur us elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus \code{<div>} et netus et malesuada fames ac tur pis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna f ringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tor tor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, \code{<body>} viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit \code{<html>} amet orci dignissim r utr um \\

\noindent Desired output: \code{<{\color{editorPink}div}>}

\end{document}
```

**Desired output:**

The desired output is included in the MWE.

Comment: If all of your `\code` fragments contain `<...>`, you could simply move the characters part in the defintion of `\code`. Otherwise, if we are talking html, you might consider using the [listings](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package and its command `\lstinline` which allows somewhat more advanced colouring.

Comment: Do you mean this: `\newcommand{\code}[2][editorPink]{\textless\textcolor{#1}{#2}\textgreater}` and in the document `\code{div}`(pink) or `\code[blue]{div}`(blue).

Comment: @Bobyandbob I am trying out the `\lstinline` option and I arrive to the following solution: `\newcommand{\code}[1]{{\lstinline[basicstyle=\small\ttfamily\upshape]{#1}}}` - but for some reason it's breaking the highlighting for the rest of the document.

Comment: Mistaken identity? @Timm ?. Is my comment relevant?(@kexxcream).

Comment: @Bobyandbob No, as it would take too much time to change all code inside the document. The `lstinline` option seems to do the trick, but mess up the highlighting at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried my suggestion with the `\lstinline` option, and for me it seems to work:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Colors
% --------------------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{editorBlue}{cmyk}{1, 0.35, 0, 0}
\definecolor{editorPink}{cmyk}{0, 1, 0, 0}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Command for inline code
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\code}[1]{%
    {%
        \lstset{%
            basicstyle=\small\ttfamily‌​\upshape,
            keywordstyle=\color{editorBlue},
            commentstyle=\color{editorPink},
            keepspaces 
        }%
        \lstinline[language=HTML]{#1}%
    }%
}
\begin{document}

\noindent Standard: \code{<html>} \\
\noindent More: \code{<html>  <!-- Comment -->} \\
\noindent In Text: Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus \code{<div>} et netus et malesuada fames ac tur pis egestas. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, \code{<body>} viverra ac, nunc. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit \code{<html>} amet orci dignissim r utr um \\

\end{document}
```

Gives the following result:

[image]

I moved the settings outside of the brackets, but that didn't really matter for me, it just looks nicer. In case you do not use listings anywhere else in the document, you could also move them to your preamble.

I also added some examples how to set colors, everything else should be in the package documentation.

Comment: This worked, but I had to tweak it with `basicstyle=\ttfamily\upshape\lst@ifdisplaystyle\tiny\fi,` as I am using a different style for code blocks and default style inline. In addition, I redefined the command to `\newcommand{\code}[1]{\lstinline{#1}}`

Comment: Well, of course you'll can tweak it to match your style, that's why there are the settings. Your redefinition apparently also works, however note that it now has no idea what language you are writing.

Comment: If I write `\newcommand{\inlinecodes}[1]{\lstinline[language=HTML]{#1}}` the highlighting breaks for some reason. What could cause this? Eventually I would want to switch out this to CSS.

Comment: Did you copy the exact code? If yes, please show your problem with an image or an errormessage.

Comment: Yes, it's the exact code. I'm using Texpad 1.7.36 for macOS. It's this `[language=HTML]` that disables the highlighting for the rest of the document.

Comment: Ok, I have no clue there.. there are Post on StackExchange where some people say that redefining `\lstinline` does not work, and people who say it does. And apparently it definitely worked for me, so I'm clueless here...

Comment: Is there any other way to define the language for `\lstinline`? Could this be solved somehow by using `\lstloadlanguages`?

Comment: Check the manual, I think you can load it in `\usepackage`, or maybe even in `\lstset`. If this does not help, I'd suggest to do what SE tells me and move to chat. However, not today.

Comment: I managed to solve this issue by using `\lstMakeShortInline[language=HTML5]^` instead and then directly in the document use `^<div class="test">This works well. Another.</div>^`. Notice the use of `^` as a delimiter.